# Okta .net WebApi setup questions

Tags: c#, webapi, okta

I have some issues understanding the correct configuration to secure a .net 4.8 WebAPI with Okta.

Below you can see an extract of the code where this Okta part is set up in the Startup.cs class.
Also there is the commented out version without using OktaSDK library that I used before.

I try to figure out how Okta can secure the WebAPI with only that information.

To retrieve the Okta token the request needs to provide a clientId, clientSecret and a scope.

How is this setup able to verify that the token in the request was issued for exactly this WebAPI and not for any other application that is secured by the same Okta login server?
There is nowhere the clientId or scope given to the SDK so that it would be able to verify the token against this.

The values from the configuration file are:

```
Okta:OktaDomain:  "https://<ourlogon>.okta.com/"
Okta:Authority:   "https://<ourlogon>.okta.com/oauth2/default"
Okta:AuthorizationServerId: "default" 
Okta:Audience:    "api://default"
```

The code is here:

```cs
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    log.Debug("Do Configuration");

    string oktaDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Okta:OktaDomain"];
    string oktaAuthorizationServerId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Okta:AuthorizationServerId"];
    string oktaAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Okta:Audience"];
    string oktaAuthority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Okta:Authority"];

    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    var authority = oktaAuthority;

    var configurationManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(
                      authority + "/.well-known/openid-configuration",
    new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever(),
    new HttpDocumentRetriever());
   
    var discoveryDocument = Task.Run(() => configurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    log.Debug("Setting up Okta authentication");
    try
    {
        app.UseOktaWebApi(new OktaWebApiOptions
        {
            OktaDomain = oktaDomain
            ,AuthorizationServerId = oktaAuthorizationServerId
            ,Audience = oktaAudience
        });

        //app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
        //   new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
        //   {
        //       //token handler set to try to debug issues on prod and dev
        //       //TokenHandler = new LoggingJwtSecurityTokenHandler(),
        //       AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
        //       TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        //       {
        //           ValidAudience = "api://default",
        //           ValidIssuer = authority,
        //           IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (token, securityToken, identifier, parameters) =>
        //           {
        //               return discoveryDocument.SigningKeys;
        //           }
        //       }
        //   }); ;
    } catch(Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error("Error setting up Okta authentication", ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```